# Dynamic memory allocation array of stack

Tags: c, csv, memory, struct, dynamic

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct {
    Char *name;
    int age;
    double balance;
    } info_t;
```

And the following function

```
 void readFile(FILE *file, info_t **arr){ }
```

I want to parse a cvs file and store each line (every line contain a name, age, balance) into array of struct using dynamic memory allocation. How can I do it? The buffer for each line is 256 and for each field 24. I want to dynamically allocate both the array of struct and the element inside the struct. The language is c by the way.

Comment: Generic CSV files are *deceptively* easy to parse. I say "deceptively" because there are many corner or special cases that are non-trivial to handle. I suggest you attempt to find a library which does the CSV loading and parsing for you.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you want the `readFile` function to also allocate the array, then you need to *emulate pass by reference in C*. You must do that by becoming a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: By the way, why do you need so much dynamic allocation? I can understand that you might want to save space by not creating strings where only a few characters are used, but why pointers to `info_t`? What problem is that supposed to solve? All it does is add complexity.

Comment: `void readFile(FILE *file, info_t **arr)`???  It sure would be a whole lot easier to code and therefore much less bug prone to simply ***return*** an `info_t` pointer....

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

```c
typedef struct { char* name; int age; double balance; } info_t;

// prototype of functions that need to be implemented
char* get_next_line_of_file(FILE*);
info_t parse_single_line(const char*);

// readFile() returns the number of items stored in `result`; `result` is a pointer to an array of `info_t` items
size_t readFile(FILE* file, info_t** result) {
  // our array is initially empty
  *result = NULL;
  size_t arr_size = 0;

  // let's read the lines
  while (true) {
    char* line = get_next_line_of_file(file);
    // `line` here is dynamically-allocated, so we also check that it's not NULL
    if (line == NULL) { break; }

    // let's parse the line
    info_t parsed_line = parse_single_line(line); // here is where you malloc() space for member `name` of `info_t`
    if (parsed_line.name == NULL) { break; } // `name` allocation failed

    // now that we have a new record, we can add it to the `result` array
    info_t* new_array = realloc(*result, sizeof(info_t) * (arr_size + 1));

    // if allocation went wrong, we simply return
    if (new_array == NULL) {
      free(parsed_line.name); // we avoid memory leaks
      break;
    }

    // since `new_array` is valid, we can now update `*result`
    *result = new_array;
    arr_size += 1; // we update array's size

    // the newly-added record must be equal to the newly-parsed line
    (*result)[arr_size - 1] = parsed_line;
  }

  return arr_size;
}

// that's how you use the previous function
int main(void) {
  FILE* file = fopen(...);

  info_t* arr;
  size_t arr_size = readFile(file, &arr);

  // let's print all records
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i += 1) {
    printf("%s, %d, %lf\n", arr[i].name, arr[i].age, arr[i].balance);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Is this what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I admire the work you've put into this (assuming it's your work and not a copy/paste from somewhere else), but a wall of code without explanation isn't very instructive.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's a quick draft I wrote just for this question, I've put some comments to explain the various steps of the function, but maybe you say it's not enough explicative? (just asking, I may add more comments). The OP can use this code as an approach to write generic dynamically-allocated array generators. P.S.: in my opinion the crucial parts of the function (but that are not strictly part of the question) are `get_next_line_of_file()` and `parse_single_line()`, and that's why their implementation is left to OP.

Comment: You could/should add a comment for the block/lines of the last three lines of `readFile` to explain what they're doing. The code is _well_ commented otherwise. IMO, well done/placed comments in code are sometimes better than a separate description of the code [without comments].

Comment: @CraigEstey I've commented last lines as per your suggestion.